# can this code be re-written to use jquery chaining for setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use chaining when using setTimeout(). This example gives a div a red background, then I use setTimeout() to wait a second and make the background back to normal. can it be re-written or improved in any way

```
$(target).css('background', 'red');
setTimeout(function(){
   $(target).css('background', '');
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a performance improvement if your cache your jQuery call:

```
var target = $(target);
target.css('background', 'red');
setTimeout(function(){
   target.css('background', '');
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am almost positive delay will not work unless the items are a part of an effects queue or custom queue. That said, I don't know if this would be very efficient, but it uses chaining like you asked:

```
$(target)
    .queue('fx', function(next) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red').delay(800);
        next();
    })
    .queue('fx', function(next) {
       $(this).css('background', '');
       next();
    })
    .dequeue('fx');
```

Comment: it seems that you got error `$(this).('background', 'red').delay(800);` and it isn't working either, what's up with this `css()` function, it is not working with delay method

Comment: The css method acts immediately on the item you are working with. The delay method does not act on the element, it delays execution of effects in the effects queue. So delay would move immediately onto the next css method, since its not a part of the effects queue. (Also, those -1s weren't from me)

Comment: yes .. now I understand and somehow managed to fix my code too

Answer (score -1):

you can use the "delay" function in jquery like

$(target).delay(1000).css('background','');

this function is only available in jquery 1.4 and next version.

Please check it also

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score -1):

**[EDIT]**

I think you can do this using [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) function.

```
$(target).css('background', 'red').delay(5000).queue(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
});
```

See live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R68yy/).

Comment: Delay acts on items in the effects queue; code would delay any processing of the effects queue by 100ms.